# How to put a gag order on "ignoring invalid setDrawableSize" printed all over the console on ios

Tags: ios, core-graphics

What's that:

> CAMetalLayer ignoring invalid setDrawableSize width=0.000000
> height=0.000000

and how do I stop this from spilling over my console?

Can't see a thing over this. This is not an app using metal directly
though I'm not sure about Lottie and others. CoreAnimation should be aplenty
for that fw but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suggests that something in your app, or in one of the libraries your app uses (like Lottie or others), is attempting to set the drawable size of a CAMetalLayer to (0,0) which is not valid.

There are a few steps you can take to identify and potentially fix the issue:

Identifying the Source: Before hiding the log, try to identify what triggers it. It might be a UI component being temporarily set to zero size, perhaps during layout adjustments, animations, or transitions.

Lottie: If you are using Lottie, ensure you have the latest version of the library. Sometimes, library maintainers fix these kinds of issues in newer releases.

Workaround: As a temporary measure, you can filter out this specific warning from Xcode’s console to see other logs:

Open the scheme editor (Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme or ⌘<)
Go to the "Run" phase on the left
Under the "Info" tab, find the "Environment Variables" section
Add the variable OS_ACTIVITY_MODE and set its value to disable.
This will stop all the OS-related logs, but it's only a workaround. It's important to know that using this approach will filter out all system logs, so only use it temporarily until you solve the actual issue.

Inspect Third-party Libraries: If you're using any third-party libraries that might be interacting with Metal or Core Animation, investigate if any of them are known to cause such logs. You might want to see if there are updates available for those libraries or if there are open issues related to this warning.

Fallback to OpenGL: If you identify a specific component or library causing this with Metal, and you can't find a direct fix, check if there's an option to switch the renderer from Metal to OpenGL (if applicable and available). For example, Lottie on iOS defaults to using Metal but can be set to use OpenGL.

Contact Library Authors: If a third-party library is the cause and you can't find a solution, consider reaching out to the library's maintainers or checking the library's GitHub issues to see if others have faced a similar issue.

It's always best to address the root cause of such warnings rather than just suppressing them. The warning indicates that there might be something not quite right with the layer setup or usage, and while it might not cause an immediate issue, it's usually a good idea to understand why it's happening.

Comment: Right, root causing this would be best but there does not seem to be a way to put a breakpoint on it.